# Do two threads started in consecutive statements run at the same time, or do they run one after another?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, java-threads

Look at the following code. All the statements in this snippet are being executed in the main thread. 
Threads are separate units of execution, i.e. two different threads can be executing simultaneously, independent of each other, right?

So does it mean that the statement `new Thread(new Consumer()).start();` will be executed once the `new Thread(new Producer()).start();` statement's execution is complete (that is when the `Producer` thread is done with execution, that is *after the `run()` method of `Producer` has returned*)?

Or does the JVM simply gets to and starts executing the `new Thread(new Consumer()).start();` statement, right after it has *invoked* the `start()` method of the first thread, i.e. while the first `Producer` thread *is running*?

```
public class ThreadsCoordinationUsingGuardedBlocks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Producer()).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is NO guarantee as to the execution order of one or the other. This is why Java, and all sane programming languages, really, provide mechanisms so that executions can be synchronized. In Java, one such example would be a `BlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> two different threads can be executing simultaneously, independent of each other, right?

They also start independently which means they can start in any order and if one completes quickly it could stop before other has even had a chance to start.

> after the run() method of Producer has returned)?

So that is possible, it is also possible the threads will complete in the opposite order.

> Or does the JVM simply gets to and starts executing the new Thread(new Consumer()).start(); statement,

Note: the JVM doesn't implement the threads. This is the job of the OS.  All Java does is make system calls to the OS to tell it to do that.  The JVM has no idea how long after `start()` is called that the `run()` of those threads will be called.

Answer (score 2):

You should assume that the order is non-deterministic. `Thread()` is probably a schedulable event, so even on a uni-processor there is no guarantee of the order of execution and you may be running on a multi-processor as well.

Your code should explicitly handle synchronization – even if some quirk of the implementation where you run causes deterministic execution, explicit synchronization serves to communicate the intent of your code and guards against a change in the underlying thread code.